# Multiple overlay on a image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating two overlay in an image.

One overlay is fixed over the bottom of image,Second overlay will be displayed on mouse hover.

My problem is second overlay is displayed on first overlay but it should not display over the fixed one.

Sample partial  Demo is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/MbLNN/131/). Please find the screenshot too.[image]

Please help me or guid me to the right way to solve the issue or implement the design..

**HTML**

```
 <section id="s-explore">
        <div class="pagebreak"><span>The Lifestyle</span>  <i class="down">&lt;</i>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper layout">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="media">
                    <img id="d1" src="http://placekitten.com/300/300" />
                    <div class="contenthover">                  

                        <p><a href="#" class="mybutton">Lorem ipsum</a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>

        </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.contenthover{
    color:#fff;
}
.mybutton{    
    padding:20px;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#000;
    margin:10px;
}
```

**Jquery**

```
$(function () {
     $(' #d1').contenthover({
         overlay_width: 300,
         overlay_height: 150,
         effect: 'slide',
         slide_direction: 'bottom',
         overlay_x_position: 'center',
         overlay_y_position: 'bottom',
         overlay_background: '#000',
         overlay_opacity: 0.8
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Its just about the z-index of the third layer. You have to set the position of the media content to relative, position the 3 layer with absolute to the bottom and set z-index to bottom layer. That's it.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/MbLNN/134/)**

html

```
<section id="s-explore">
    <div class="pagebreak"><span>The Lifestyle</span>  <i class="down">&lt;</i>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper layout">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="media">
                <img id="d1" src="http://placekitten.com/300/300" />
                <div class="contenthover">                  

                    <p><a href="#" class="mybutton">Lorem ipsum</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="bottom_layer">colors</div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

css

```
.contenthover{
    color:#fff;
}
.mybutton{    
    padding:20px;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#000;
    margin:10px;
}
.bottom_layer{
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    background:red;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 300px;
}
.media{
    position:relative;
}
```